# Logstash appears to be forcing multicast discovery even with embedded set to true

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am getting the following warning and logstash is not forwarding to the embedded (built-in in logstash) ElasticSearch.

`WARN: org.elasticsearch.discovery: logstash [some thread id] waited for 30s and no initial state was set by the discovery`

I have the following in my logstash configuration.

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    embedded => true
  }
```

My elasticsearch.yml has the following.

```
# logstash embedded ES config
script.disable_dynamic: true
node.local: true # disable network
```

The question is how to disable discovery or make it discover the embedded ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 0):

I have sort of verified that it works but I am not sure if this really fixed it. I have to add `host => "localhost"` in my logstash output configuration.

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => "localhost"
    embedded => true
  }
```